How to fix patchy garden and turn in into lush garden
Following are the photos of my garden, It isn't anywhere near lush. to sit and enjoy. I wanted to find out how to make it lush and healthy. Why is my grass patchy, have flowers in them and other plants. There are gardens which are really lush and refreshing to the eye.
What can i do to achieve it?
I am based in Uk, North west side.




What was sitting in the location of that big rectangular spot on pics 2 and 3? (Hint: 2 more dead spots coming up under that box and whatever the black thing is)

Lack of sun and foot traffic are two obvious problems for "lush grass" in this little garden, which has shade in every picture, as well as a table and benches concentrating foot traffic, and additionally shading their area.
Pavers where foot traffic is high can reduce wear on grass. Increasing sun tends to involve trimming, thinning, or removing trees (and/or buildings.) If traffic can be concentrated onto pavers things other than grass may provide short green growth with lower light levels, as removing buildings and trees is often undesirable for other reasons.

Also, not leaving boxes and things on top of the grass which causes dead spots

I seem to recall you and I communicated about your creation of a lawn some 4 years or so back, and that you sowed seed. It seems you have not done much maintenance or lawn care on a regular basis since then, so this link https://www.rhs.org.uk/lawns/spring-summer-care should be helpful. It is, though, important you do not leave rubbish or boxes or anything else on the grass, because the grass beneath will die back and leave brown areas behind, which is likely what has happened in some dead looking areas on your lawn.
I would just say though that it might be better to consider paving the area where the table and chairs are - its a small area and that means it will suffer much wear and tear with regular foot traffic.
